# Storing multiple large arrays in one document MongoDB

Tags: performance, mongodb, gridfs

I'm creating an application that has Tinder like features. Currently Im storing a user's likes, dislikes, and matches in 3 separate collections that are structured as such

```
{
  "_id" : "user1_ID",
  "matches" : [
      {
          "matchID" : "user2_ID",
          "time" : "2015-01-16 21:19:50 America/Los_Angeles"
      }
   ]
}
```

The "_id" field holds the ID of the user who's matches we are storing and the "matches.matchID" field holds the ID's of the users that that a certain user has matched with. The "matches.time" field holds the timestamp of when they matched with that user.

The Likes and Dislikes collections are identical to the matches collection except they hold the ID's of the the users a certain user has disliked or liked.

---

The problem I currently have is that I need to query all 3 collections in order to make sure that I dont send a user other users that they have already liked, disliked, or matched with, therefore It would be easier to consolidate these 3 collections into one and structure it like so:

```
{
  "_id" : "user1_ID",
  "matches" : [
        {
          "matchID" : "user2_ID",
          "time" : "2015-01-17 15:47:15 America/Los_Angeles"
        }
   ],
   "likes" : [
        {
          "likeeID" : "user3_ID",
          "time" : "2015-01-17 15:47:15 America/Los_Angeles"
        }
   ],
   "dislikes" : [
        {
          "dlikeeID" : "user4_ID",
          "time" : "2015-01-17 15:47:15 America/Los_Angeles"
        }
   ]
}
```

Although this might make querying easier I'm afraid that these arrays might get too big and make the document too large.

What would be the correct way to store this data? I've read that gridFS helps with breaking up large documents, would this be the way to go? If so how do I go about implementing this? I'm not very familiar with how gridFS works yet.

Comment: Wen collections get big you use sharding, the strength of MongoDB. http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/sharding/ and courses are available at https://university.mongodb.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a very interesting problem.  While I imagine there might be more than one solution I would like to shed light on one in particular.  I would consider just using the one document as you stated but keeping the amount of data stored in the document down to a minimum.

For example you can rewrite your example as such and save a lot of bytes:

```
{
  "_id" : "user1_ID",
  "matches" : [
        {
          "id" : "user2_ID",
          "ts" : "1421544095534"
        }
   ],
   "likes" : [
        {
          "id" : "user3_ID",
          "ts" : "1421544095534"
        }
   ],
   "dislikes" : [
        {
          "id" : "user4_ID",
          "ts" : "1421544095534"
        }
   ]
}
```

With this approach you may be able to hold thousands of matches.  I would calculate what the max is and verify if that's enough matches for a given user.

EDIT:  Assuming each edditional entry would look like this (as far as number of chars used up):

```
{"id" : "user2_ID", "ts" : "1421544095534"},
```

That's about 44 bytes.  We can round up to 50 bytes. That;s about 320,000 entries you can fit in one BSON document.